# It it possible to take a snapshot for Java Profilers with Java?

Tags: java, jvm, profiler, snapshot

I would like to periodically take a snapshot of my runtime (the .snapshot files used on profilers for Java, like YourKit, JProfiler, VisualVM, etc), is possible to take a snapshot by calling a method or something else? With Java, running on the same jvm?

Comment: write a shell-script having jcmd, jmap, etc. commands and add this script as a cron job

Comment: What do you want to take a snapshot of? You can get a thread dump using `jstack`

Answer (score 1):

**I would suggest periodically running a Java Flight Recorder.**

What is it? It is a profiling tool similar to the ones you already mentioned, it captures [all the usual data](https://www.waitingforcode.com/public/images/articles/jfr_jmc_recording_result.png).

How to use it? [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH176) is a short description on how to start it up. Be careful that **the application you want to profile needs these extra JVM params**:

```
java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder
```

And finally for a periodic scheduling you need a command that you can use from crontab. For that you can use the example command from the previous link:

```
jcmd 5368 JFR.start duration=60s filename=myrecording.jfr
```

Where "5368" is the PID of your profiled application and the rest is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Each profiler will have a different mechanism for periodically saving snapshots.

For [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), use a "Timer" trigger with a "Save snapshot" action. If you want to record data for a limited time just before saving the snapshot, add the following sequence of trigger actions:

- "Start recording" (with the desired recording types selected)
- "Sleep" (for the desired amount of time)
- "Stop recording"
- "Save snapshot" (with "add unique number to file name" selected)

[image]

If you would rather like to control recording and saving snapshots programmatically from the same JVM, use the [Controller API](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/api/javadoc/com/jprofiler/api/agent/Controller.html) like this:

```
Controller.startCPURecording(true);
Thread.sleep(10000);
Controller.saveSnapshot(new File("snapshot.jps"));
```

Comment: Can you tell me if snapshot taken by that way is also compatible with another profilers?

Comment: No, snapshots are always tied to a particular profiler, because all profilers record different types of data. One exception are HPROF heap snapshots which can read be most profilers.